# Symfony2 does not redirect to a new page after pdf generation with tcpdf

Tags: redirect, symfony, tcpdf

I have a controller which should generate pdf file and after that should redirect to another site.

```php
class DocuController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction() {
          // some other code
            if ($request->get('_add_document'))
            {
                $form->bindRequest($request);
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
                $em->persist($document);      
                $em->flush();   
                if ($session->get('journey_id')!=false)
                {
                    $relation = new DocumentJourneyInJourney();
                    $relation->setJourney($session->get('journey_id'));
                    $relation->setDocument($document->getId());
                    $em->persist($relation);
                    $em->flush();
                }
                $pdf=$this->generatePDF($form);   
                $pdf->Output('file.pdf', 'I');

                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('another_site'));
            }
    }        
    return $this->render('Bundle:Page:document.html.twig'); 
}

public function generatePDF($form)
{
    $pdf = $this->get("wrep.tcpdf")->create();
    $pdf->SetTitle('Tittle');        
    $pdf->SetHeaderData('', 0, '  ', '  ', array(0,0,0), array(0,0,0)); 
    $pdf->setHeaderFont(array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
    $pdf->SetPrintFooter(false);  
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE);         
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $html = $this->renderView('Bundle:document.twig',
                    array(
                    'traveller' => $form["name"]->getData().' '.$form["surname"]->getData(),
                    'document' => $form["full_name"]->getData()
                    )
                );  
    $pdf->writeHTML($html, $ln=false, $fill=false, $reseth=false, $cell=false, $align='');
    return $pdf;
}
}
```

But with this code the pdf is generated and browser downloading it but the page is not redirected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible. You can only try to use javascript to do that. Create a iframe load there the pdf download url and redirect the user after calling the iframe with the pdf with javascript. (I don't know if it really works) The other question is why do you need to redirect the user?

Comment: On site with this controller is form and button 'generate pdf', so I wanted to generate pdf file, let user to download the file and then redirect him to the for example home page.

Comment: Redirect the user to the homepage. At the homepage add javascript to redirect the user to the pdf. The PDF download starts while the user still stays on the homepage.

Answer (score 0):

That's normal. Your response has been sent when you dowloaded the file. It's too to send a redirect response.

Comment: Thanks for reply, could you tell me how to resolve my problem? I mean, what do you suggest to do to accomplish redirect after pdf downloading.

Comment: I have no suggestion, because you can't redirect from a pdf, can you? Why not stay on the page where you are?

Comment: I thought there will be some solution, but I see there is no other option. Thanks for help.